# On the asymptotics of $\int_0^\infty \exp\big(\!-\!\lambda e^x/x\big)\,dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics, laplace-method

The question is about the asymptotics of $$I(\lambda):=\int_0^\infty \exp\big(\!-\!\lambda e^x/x\big)\,dx$$ as $\lambda\to\infty$. I ask this question here because this is a non-standard form of an integrand that can be treated nevertheless by the saddle point approximation. I also believe the results to be quite elegant. Lastly, this is an integral that *Mathematica* struggles to numerically evaluate, so I thought that it would be useful to be able to know how to analytically approximate it.

Comment: I did not face any problem for the numerical evaluation of the integral. For $\lambda=250$, the result is $7.06459\times 10^{-297}$. Your formula gives $7.06762*10^{-297}$.

Comment: Good to know. I had trouble plotting the integral for various $\lambda$. Might have been an inefficiency in my code.

Comment: In Mathematica **13.2.0** you can use: `AsymptoticIntegrate[
 Exp[-\[Lambda]*Exp[x]/x], {x, 0, Infinity}, {\[Lambda], Infinity, 1}]` gives: $$e^{-\frac{1}{2}-e \lambda } \sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{\frac{1}{\lambda }}$$

Answer (score 2):

We treat this integral using the saddle-point approximation. Let $f(x)=-\frac{\exp(x)}{x}$. Then we have $f\le 0$, $f(0)=0$, $f(\infty)=0$ and $f$ has a maximum at $x=1$ with $f(1)=-e, f''(1)=-e$. Hence, extending the integration range to the full real line, we have that
$$I(\lambda)\sim\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\big(\!-\!\lambda\big(e+\frac{e}{2}(x-1)^2\big)\big)\,dx.$$
Doing the Gaussian integral, we find that
$$I(\lambda)\sim \frac{\exp\left(-\lambda e\right)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{e}}.$$

Comment: Of course, this is the same as applying Laplace method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method

Answer (score 2):

We split the integral at $x=1$ into two parts:
$$
I(\lambda ) = \int_0^1 {\exp ( - \lambda {\rm e}^x /x)\,{\rm d}x}  + \int_1^{ + \infty } {\exp ( - \lambda {\rm e}^x /x)\,{\rm d}x} .
$$
Using the two real branches of the [Lambert $W$-function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13), we perform the substitutions $x =  - W_0 (t)$ and $x =  - W_{ - 1} (t)$, respectively, to get
$$
I(\lambda ) = \int_0^{ - 1/{\rm e}} {\exp (\lambda /t)\,{\rm d}( - W_0 (t))}  + \int_{ - 1/{\rm e}}^0 {\exp (\lambda /t)\,{\rm d}( - W_{ - 1} (t))} .
$$
Now making the change of variables $t =  - 1/s$ yields
\begin{align*}
I(\lambda ) & = \int_{ + \infty }^{\rm e} {{\rm e}^{ - \lambda s} \,{\rm d}( - W_0 ( - 1/s))}  + \int_{\rm e}^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - \lambda s}\, {\rm d}( - W_{ - 1} ( - 1/s))} 
\\ & = \int_{\rm e}^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - \lambda s} \left[ {\frac{{{\rm d}W_0 ( - 1/s)}}{{{\rm d}s}} - \frac{{{\rm d}W_{ - 1} ( - 1/s)}}{{{\rm d}s}}} \right]{\rm d}s} .
\end{align*}
Finally, with $s = {\rm e} + x$, we deduce
$$
I(\lambda ) = {\rm e}^{ - {\rm e}\lambda } \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - \lambda x} \left[ {\frac{{{\rm d}W_0 ( - 1/({\rm e} + x))}}{{{\rm d}x}} - \frac{{{\rm d}W_{ - 1} ( - 1/({\rm e} + x))}}{{{\rm d}x}}} \right]{\rm d}x} .
$$
Near the branchpoint $-1/{\rm e}$, we have
$$
W_{0,1}( - 1/({\rm e} + x)) =  - \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( \mp 1)^n c_n (\sqrt {2\log (1 + x/{\rm e})} )^n } 
$$
(cf. [$(4.13.6)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13.E6)). Consequently,
\begin{align*}
W_0 ( - 1/({\rm e} + x)) - W_{ - 1} ( - 1/({\rm e} + x)) & = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {2c_{2n + 1} (2\log (1 + x/{\rm e}))^{n + 1/2} } \\ & = 2\sqrt {\frac{2}{{\rm e}}} x^{1/2}  - \frac{7}{{{\rm 18e}}}\sqrt {\frac{2}{{\rm e}}} x^{3/2}  +  \ldots 
\end{align*}
as $x\to 0^+$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{{{\rm d}W_0 ( - 1/({\rm e} + x))}}{{{\rm d}x}} - \frac{{{\rm d}W_{ - 1} ( - 1/({\rm e} + x))}}{{{\rm d}x}} = \sqrt {\frac{2}{{\rm e}}} x^{ - 1/2}  - \frac{7}{{{\rm 12e}}}\sqrt {\frac{2}{{\rm e}}} x^{1/2}  +  \ldots 
$$
as $x\to 0^+$. Hence, by Watson's lemma,
$$
I(\lambda ) \sim {\rm e}^{ - {\rm e}\lambda } \sqrt {\frac{{2\pi }}{{{\rm e}\lambda }}} \left( {1 - \frac{7}{{24{\rm e}\lambda }} +  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $\lambda \to +\infty$. It is seen that the natural variable is ${\rm e}\lambda$.